# Check whether nodes exist in a neo4j graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

*NOTE*

I let this become several questions instead of the simple one I asked, so I am breaking the follow-ups off into their own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867148/creating-unique-relationships-without-creating-unique-nodes-in-neo4j).

*ORIGINAL QUESTION*

I'm receiving a list of IDs that I am first testing whether any of them are in my graph, and if they /are/ I am processing those nodes further.

So, for example...

```
fids = get_fids(record)  # [100001, 100002, 100003, ... etc]
ids_in_my_graph = filter(id_is_in_graph, fids) # [100002]

def id_is_in_graph(id):
    val = False
    query = """MATCH (user:User {{id_str:"{}"}})
    RETURN user
    """.format(id)
    n=neo4j.CypherQuery(graph_db,query).execute_one()
    if n:
        val = True
    return(val)
```

As you can imagine, doing this with filter, sequentially testing whether each ID is in my graph is really, really slow, and is clearly not properly using neo4j.

How would I rephrase my query such that I could create a list like `(User{id_str: [mylist]})` to query and return only IDs that are in my graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use WHERE...IN by exploiting the collection functionality of cypher.  [Here's the relevant reference](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-where.html#_collections)

So your query might look like this:

```
MATCH (user:User) 
WHERE user.id_str IN ["100001", "100002", "100003"]
return user;
```

Now, I don't know how large a collection can be.  I doubt this would work if your collection had 1,000 items in it.  But at least this is a way of batching them up into chunks.  This should improve performance.

Also have a look at the Collections section of the [Cypher 2.0 refcard](http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use cypher with parameters, like {id} and then pass `"id"-> record.id` to the execution

```
MATCH (user:User {id_str:{user_id}}),(friend:User {id_str:{friend_id}})
CREATE UNIQUE (user)-[:FRIENDS]->(friend)

{ "user_id" : record.id, "friend_id" : i}
```

Make sure to add a

```
create unique constraint on (u:User) assert u.id is unique;
```

And you can send multiple statements at once to the transactional http endpoint for cypher:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html

Which is probably already supported by your driver.

Comment: Won't this create many Users who are not already in my graph?  I thought CREATE UNIQUE path would create both the relationship /and/ the nodes if the nodes do not already exist.